# Jadira usertype no class def found

Tags: hibernate, jodatime

I'm trying to persist a JODA LocalDate attribute using Hibernate.

```
@Column(nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime scheduledDepartureTime;
```

I downloaded the following jars:

```
usertype.jodatime-2.0.1.jar
usertype.spi-3.0.0.GA.jar
usertype.core-3.0.0.GA.jar
```

and added them to my classpath.

When trying to execute my application, I get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.shared.spi.AbstractSingleColumnUserType
```

When searching for this class in Eclipse, I can find it, but it is located in
`org.jadira.usertype.shared.spi`, which explains the Exception

Any idea why this class is searched in the wrong package ? Since I'm using the latest version of these jars, I doubt this comes from version problem.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usertype.core-3.0.0.GA.jar` contains `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime` that you need.
Use only two dependencies:

```
usertype.spi-3.0.0.GA.jar
usertype.core-3.0.0.GA.jar
```