# Which Jars I'm confused... Usertype, hibernate 4, JodaTime

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jodatime, usertype

I have identified that I need to use

```
<mapping class="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate" />
<mapping class="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime" />
```

classes for persisting in the database. I am really confused regarding which jars to download for these two classes I want to persist.

Should I use joda time classes and usertype classes to persist, what is the relation between them. I am using hibernate 4.

I also see that there is `3.2.0GA and 3.2.0CR11` what does this mean. In the maven repository for many of the packages it is written adds hibernate support! but which version? 
I am trying to solve this from 3 days now...

Comment: If you are going to do some stuff with Date/Time then use `Joda` otherwise you can use simple date time of java inbuilt. if time manipulation you want to do then you ll have to use `PersistentLocalDateTime`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jadira usertype no class def found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916752/jadira-usertype-no-class-def-found)

Comment: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.jadira.usertype|usertype.jodatime|2.0.1|jar

Comment: Now I am getting this error:
    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator not a subtype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Joda Time User Type classes are not meant for mappings. You map entities, not `UserTypes`.

Hibernate defines the following data structures:

1. An Entity is the Object equivalent of a database row. It has an @Id that maps to the associated row's primary key.
2. An Embeddable is an Object that maps to one or more columns except for the primary key. It's always depended on the parent Entity.
3. Both Entity and Embeddable may contain non-primary key column mappings, and the Java-to-SQL type bridge is being handled by Hibernate Types.
4. You can define your own User Types to represent other structures such as Money or Currency.

So, the Jadira types are bridging the Joda DateTime Object types to DATE, TIME, and TIMESTAMP SQL types. If you don't need to use Joda, you'd have to rely on `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar` or `java.sql.Date` for your Entity property types.

Comment: I request sincerely an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775307/secondary-cache-hibernate-compatibility-issue you will also get an answer and an upvote, it should be simple for you.